# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/hassankhokhar/Documents/NodeAsync/dummy.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, json, cors, local

> The issue is I cannot access this local Json file named as dummy and this is blocked in chrome as something cors issue.

```html
const getTodos = (callback) => {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest()

  request.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
      const data = request.responseText
      if (request.status === 200) {
        callback(undefined, JSON.parse(data))
      } else {
        callback('! Could Not Fetch', data)
      }
    }
  })

  request.open('GET', 'dummy.json')
  request.send()
}

console.log('1')

getTodos((err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(data)
  }
})

console.log('2')
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using html and using js script in head and if I use http-server to run my simple html project on http://127.0.0.1:8081 it is not blocking, So maybe this is the solution. But I am not 100% that this is good.